# Paddle Ocr handwritten text and number detection from cheque

Tags: ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am trying to detect information from check such as pay  name and date and other, I want to use paddle OCR
currently I am using bounding box to get specific area image which I feed to paddle OCR and get the result

I have tried

[image]

```
with open(r'C:\Users\samir\Desktop\Signature\json\anna.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')

if "amount in words" in region_name:
    result = ocr.ocr(gray, det=False, cls=False)
    print("amount in words",result)
```

[image]